# How can I mark a logical partition as active?

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I need to fix the bootsector on my Windows 7 partition by using this command from a rescue disk:

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

However my Windows 7 partition needs to be marked active by Windows to do this (or you get the `Element not found` error). The Windows 7 partition is in an extended partition so when you use `diskpart` to try to make that partition active, it complains that it cannot make that type of partition active.

How do I make a logical partition active (in the Windows way)?

[image: GParted]

**EDIT:** It appears that you *cannot* mark a logical partition as active, according to [this webpage](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/structPartitions-c.html) says:

> In terms of how the disk is used, there are only two main differences between a primary and a logical partition or volume. The first is that a primary partition can be set as bootable (active) while a logical cannot. The second is that DOS assigns drive letters (C:, D: etc.) differently to primary and logical volumes.

**Solution:** For those who are in the same situation as me: I made my "Steam" partition active (its a primary ntfs partition) by going into Repair Mode of the Windows 7 install disk and doing the following commands:

```
diskpart
list disks
select disk 0
list partitions
select partition 3
active
```

and then using the "Startup Recovery" option. Now my Steam partition has the bootloader but it loads up my Win7 logical partition. I also updated GRUB2 accordingly (you don't need this if you aren't using linux) by placing this in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and running `sudo update-grub`:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)"
{
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(hd0,3)
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set <Your UUID Here>
    chainloader +1
}
```

You may also need to use these commands if it still doesn't work (don't use the last with GRUB):

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Comment: I used this method and selected partition 1 (system reserved and primary partition) and my windows booted successfully, you have no idea how your solution saved my time! so THANKS

Comment: I used this method and selected partition 1 (system reserved and primary partition) and my windows booted successfully, you have no idea how your solution saved my time! so THANKS

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **[Partition Table Doctor](http://www.ptdd.com/)** for jobs like this, never failed me and saved my bacon countless times, works fine with [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/).

[image]

*Partition Table Doctor is shareware ($49.95), try before you buy.*

*Bart's Pe Builder is freeware.*